# Resolving a Mongoose Promise Call Immediately

Tags: mongoose, promise

My code executes the Promise `const voters = Player.countDocuments({})` line at the end of the code, but I need it to resolve immediately so its value can be used in the remaining code.

What can I do to have it run essentially as a synchronous line? I have tried using functions to separate the code, taking it out of the socket, using async/await, using .resolve().then(), etc. but it always resolves after I want to tally the votes.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('direction vote', (individualVote) => {

        var voteCount = 1; 
        var yesVotes = 1;

        // count the number of players that will be in the game
        const voters = Player.countDocuments({})
            .then((voterCount) =>{console.log('voterCount: ' + voterCount);});
        

        // receive the votes and tally them
        if (individualVote == 'yes') {
            yesVotes ++;
            voteCount ++;
            console.log('yesVotes: ' + yesVotes);
        };
        console.log('voters: ' + voters); // this resolves as the promise's object
        if (voteCount == voters) {
            // stuff happens

            // send the vote results to everyone
            io.emit('direction vote result', voteResult);
        };
    }); 
});
```

Edit: per Bergi's comment, this is how I had async/await employed.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('direction vote', (individualVote) => {

        var voteCount = 1; 
        var yesVotes = 1;
        
**      // count the number of players that will be in the game
        async function count() {
            const countVoters = await Player.countDocuments({});
            console.log('countVoters: ' + countVoters);
            return countVoters;
        }
        var voters = count();
        console.log('voters: ' + voters);
**

        // receive the votes and tally them
        if (individualVote == 'yes') {
            yesVotes ++;
            voteCount ++;
            console.log('yesVotes: ' + yesVotes);
        };
        console.log('voters: ' + voters); // this resolves as the promise's object
        if (voteCount == voters) {
            // stuff happens

            // send the vote results to everyone
            io.emit('direction vote result', voteResult);
        };
    }); 
});
```

Comment: No, it's impossible to get data from the database immediately. You need to wait for it. Do not attempt to write synchronous code. "*It always resolves after I want to tally the votes.*"  - you cannot make it resolve *earlier*. Change your approach and instead do tally the votes *later*, after the promise resolves.

Comment: Please show us *how* you use `async`/`await` or `.then()`. These are indeed the solution.

Comment: `var voters = count();` still returns a promise since it's still an `async`hronous function - the code doesn't magically become synchronous. No, you need to move the entire rest of your code inside that `async` function, after the `await`.

Comment: That did the trick, many thanks!